# How to check whether the entered date is in the correct format?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a textbox where a user is supposed to enter a date. How can I check whether the entered date is in the correct date format?

> Like this: `02/02/2008`

- not like this `022/22/-1`
- not like this `2009/02/02`
- not like this `02/Jun/2015`
- not like this `02/abc/2010`

(I don't want to use DateTimePicker or MonthCalender).

EDIT 1

I tried it like this

```
Private Sub txtHireDate_Validated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtHireDate.Validated
    Dim dateString As String = txtHireDate.Text
    Dim formats As String = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    Dim dateValue As DateTime

    If DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, New CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, dateValue) Then

    End If
```

But its showing some errors

[image]

Comment: Note that even if you use a control to fill your textbox, it's still a good idea to validate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx) function:

```
String dateString = dateTextBox.Text;
String formats = "MM/dd/yyyy";
DateTime dateValue;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, 
                              new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                              DateTimeStyles.None, 
                              out dateValue))
{
    // That means the value of the date is in the specified format..
}
```

Dont forget to use the `Globalization` `namespace`:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Comment: What is this for `new CultureInfo("en-US")`

Comment: Use it if you want to specify a _culture_ for the `datetime` value .. You can ignore it and use `NULL` instead.

Comment: You need to use en-CA, not en-US.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following regexp in a `FormatValidator` control under the textbox:

```
^(19|20)\d\d[- /.]?(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.]?(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

This is in year-month-day format, and allows for the following formats:

- yyyy-MM-dd
- yyyyMMdd
- yyyy/MM/dd
- yyyy.MM.dd

Note that year month day format cannot be confused when working with standard north american dates.  American format (MM/dd/yyyy) will parse differently than Canadian format (dd/MM/yyyy), but you won't know it's wrong until you hit days higher than 12...

Example of adding a validator to the page:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="txtTreatmentDate_FormatValidator" runat="server" 
    Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="LogSave"
    ControlToValidate="txtTreatmentDate" ValidationExpression="ThisIsIgnored"
    ErrorMessage="*Invalid Date" />
```

Then in your code behind (C#)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtTreatmentDate_FormatValidator.ValidationExpression = DateHandler.DateFormatStandardRegex;
}
```

In DateHandler (with time format as well, if you need it):

```
public static readonly String DateFormatStandardRegex = "^(19|20)\\d\\d[- /.]?(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.]?(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$";
public static readonly String TimeFormat24HourRegexp = "(20|21|22|23|[01]\\d):?([0-5]\\d):?([0-5]\\d(\\.\\d*)?)?";
```

Since you didn't specify the format you were looking for (I assume US) I didn't modify this to work for you, but it's a simple matter of moving the blocks around and changing the allowed delimiters.

Canadian Format:

```
"^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](0[1-9]|1[012])[/](19|20)\\d\\d$";
```

When parsing the date, you'll definitely want to use ParseExact with EN-CA (I think that's the short form) culture, or specify the format string you want the date to comply to (i.e. "dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: Additinally, I just pulled the escaping out of my answer.  I store this regexp in a utility class, and rather than copying it into each validation control, I add it to the validator on page load.

Comment: Well I am gonna use the Canadian format. I have no experience with regexp , could you tell me how to use your code ?

Comment: In your button that submits the page, you'll have to add `ValidationGroup="LogSave"` or whatever validation group you want to use.  In this case, it was for a medical log.

Comment: I highly advise against it, especially if your code will ever make it to another country.  I'll add the regexp though, if you're dead set on using it...

Comment: Note that the question is about Winforms, not Web forms. So this answer doesn’t really apply here. And when not bound to the `FormatValidator`, using `DateTime.TryParse(Exact)` is certainly a better solution than a homebrew regular expression.

Comment: @Kendrick: Is not Failed_Noob work on a windows-based application ??

Comment: @Konrad - So regular expressions are for Web forms ?

Comment: @Akram - Yes I am working on a Windows based Application (Windows Form)

Comment: @Failed_Noob Not necessarily. But only in Web forms do you have the `FormatValidator`. You can also use regular expressions in Winforms. But using `DateTime` for the validation is superior.

Comment: @Failed_Noob, no, you can use the regexp anywhere.  I don't do winforms, so I don't know how you'd add a validator, but I'm sure there's a way.  The part that doesn't apply is the ASP.NET `ASP:RegularExpressionValidator` tag.  There must be an equivalent validator in winforms, but you'd add it to the form differently.

Comment: @Failed_Noob, I was wrong.  @Konrad Rudolph is correct that there doesn't seem to be validator controls in winforms (at least not by default).  You'd have to validate it manually when the textbox loses focus, in which case you might as well just parse the date since you'll have to do it anyway...